# detecting single nil argument in lua

Tags: function, lua, null

Is it possible to distinguish the call

```
myFunc()
```

from

```
myFunc(nil)
```

inside the function myFunc?

Comment: I don't think so. Besides, why would you want to do that?

Comment: It's a strange case, I'm sketching on a basic system with getters / setters, lua has excellent support for this using metamethods __index, __newindex. However, I want to keep this simple as I also intend to support a js backend (I'm generating code)

Comment: "It's a strange case" seems enough.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is actually possible to distinguish a `nil` value from no value in Lua functions, providing they are expecting a variable number of arguments with the `...` operator. It is not necessary very easy nor reasonable to exploit this, though. Example:

```
function myFunc(...)
  if select('#', ...) == 0 then
    print "Called without argument"
  elseif select('#', ...) == 1 and select(1, ...) == nil then
    print "Called with a nil argument"
  end
end
```

Comment: Interestingly enough, `#{...}` doesn't work in this case whereas `select('#', ...)` does. `select` also works correctly in the case of `1, nil, 2`, whereas `#{...}` returns 1 (as documented).